Сдвиг элементов при масштабировании страницы
Элементы menu-open-button и cssplay-menu расположены по центру страницы при помощи позиционирования через absolute и vh и vw. Однако при изменении ширины экрана, они смещаются как относительно центра, так и относительно друг друга.
 Как сделать чтобы элементы находились точно в центре и не изменяли положение?
Ссылка на код:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17O-YvUvzwKKwkvbxXR6ziQieg1-W1Ssa/view?usp=sharing

Не надо по ссылке. Тут просто хтмл и цсс. Приведи воспроизводимый код здесь в песочнице.

620 строк кода? зачем. html файлы безопасно качать

@Elijah_Pris а вы уберите все лишнее, что не имеет отношения к вопросу. Предоставьте модельный код, который иллюстрирует проблему.

Блоки с absolute должны находиться внутри блоков с relative, тогда этого не будет происходить
